# How can I get only name from this query?

Tags: php, sparql, wikidata

Please any help on getting only name from this query and disregard all the urls?

```
<?php

    $endpointUrl = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql';
    $sparqlQuery = <<< 'SPARQL'
    SELECT ?disc_jockey ?disc_jockeyLabel ?name WHERE {
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
      ?disc_jockey wdt:P106 wd:Q130857.
      OPTIONAL { ?disc_jockey wdt:P2561 ?name. }
    }

    SPARQL;

    echo file_get_contents( $endpointUrl . '?query=' . urlencode( $sparqlQuery )  );
?>
```

Comment: <?php

$endpointUrl = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql';
$sparqlQuery = <<< 'SPARQL'
SELECT ?disc_jockey ?disc_jockeyLabel ?name WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  ?disc_jockey wdt:P106 wd:Q130857.
  OPTIONAL { ?disc_jockey wdt:P2561 ?name. }
}

SPARQL;

echo file_get_contents( $endpointUrl . '?query=' . urlencode( $sparqlQuery )  );

Comment: Edit it into the question...

Comment: If you run the code you will se url and names but I need only names

Comment: What do you  mean AbraCadaver?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you understand the query that's running now?  Have you looked at the results you get?  The solution seems fairly obvious to me, even if you don't understand much of what's going on...

Comment: AbraCadaver was suggesting that you put the query that's in your first comment, into the question (which it was, but invisibly, because it wasn't formatted properly, which I've fixed for you).

Comment: I don;t understand the question, Did you write the SPARQL query or is it opy and paste? I mean, the part after `SELECT`, what do you think it's used for? Just select the `?name` only or not? Or do it on the client side, you have to process the result anyways or not?

Comment: If you interested in given names, replace `wdt:P2561` with `wdt:P735`.

Answer (score 0):

So, do you have access to manipulate that <strike>sql</strike> SPARQL string directly?  If so, just remove the `?disc_jockey ?disc_jockeyLabel` from the query:

```
<?php $endpointUrl = 'query.wikidata.org/sparql'; $sparqlQuery = <<< 'SPARQL' SELECT ?name WHERE { SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } ?disc_jockey wdt:P106 wd:Q130857. OPTIONAL { ?disc_jockey wdt:P2561 ?name. } } SPARQL; echo file_get_contents( $endpointUrl . '?query=' . urlencode( $sparqlQuery ) );
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

From the looks of the return value, there is no data for the `name` tag.  If you plug in the following url into your browser, you will get the file that contains the entire string:

https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=%27SELECT%20%3Fname%20WHERE%20%7B%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ130857.%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP2561%20%3Fname.%20%7D%20%7D%27

If you look in that file, you will see that there is no "`name`" xml node.  Is it possible that the where clause is incorrect?

If you remove the `?disc_jockey ?disc_jockeyLabel` you receive a blank resultset.  It contains the correct number of records, there is just no nodes to display because `name` doesn't seem to be one of the nodes.

https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20%3Fname%20WHERE%20%7B%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ130857.%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP2561%20%3Fname.%20%7D%20%7D

Am I confused or is something missing?

Possibly, you are really wanting just the `disc_jockeyLabel`?

https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=SELECT%20%3Fdisc_jockeyLabel%20WHERE%7BSERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ130857.%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fdisc_jockey%20wdt%3AP2561%20%3Fname.%20%7D%7D

Once you retrieve this information, you can iterate through them gathering all of the literal nodes.